# Error en conexion nodejs mongoDB

Tags: android, nodejs, mongodb

Tengo un `login` con un registro creado en Nodejs y conectado a MongoDB. Cuando registro a un usuario tengo una opción para reestablecer la contraseña y que le envíe un `hash` con su `token`. Cuando inserto ese código para que me de la opción de cambiar la contraseña me sale el siguiente error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: 
Invalid status code: undefined
at ServerResponse.writeHead (_http_server.js:246:11)
at ServerResponse.writeHead 
(C:\Users\NaXeTons\Desktop\loginupdate\Login\Server\node- 
login\node_modules\on-headers\index.js:44:26)
at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (_http_server.js:237:8)
at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:659:9)
at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:776:5)
at ServerResponse.send 
(C:\Users\NaXeTons\Desktop\loginupdate\Login\Server\node- 
login\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:221:10)
at ServerResponse.json 
(C:\Users\NaXeTons\Desktop\loginupdate\Login\Server\node- 
login\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
at C:\Users\NaXeTons\Desktop\loginupdate\Login\Server\node- 
login\routes.js:126:41
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:1716) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. 
This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without 
a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). 
To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI 
flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see 
https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection 
id: 2)
(node:1716) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are 
deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will 
terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
POST /users/correo@gmail.com/password - 2.386 ms - -
```

Aquí mi código de `password reset` de Node envía correctamente el `token`, pero a la hora poner el `token` no cambia nada y me salta el error de arriba.

```
exports.resetPasswordInit = email =>

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const random = randomstring.generate(8);

    user.find({ email: email })

        .then(users => {

            if (users.length == 0) {

                reject({ status: 404, message: 'User Not Found !' });

            } else {

                let user = users[0];

                const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
                const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(random, salt);

                user.temp_password = hash;
                user.temp_password_time = new Date();

                return user.save();
            }
        })

        .then(user => {
            var mailOptions = {
                from: 'prueba@gmail.com',
                to: email,
                subject: 'Cambio de pass',
                  html: '<b>Buenas '+user.name+ '</b><br> le informamos que se han realizado una solicitud de reseteo de password<br/>Si es usted, introduzca el siguiente token:'+
                  '<b>'+ random +'</b><br><br>Si estas abriendo esto desde el dispositivo android acceda a este enlace: <a href = "http://nachetons/'+random+'">link</a><br>'+
                  /*AQUI PONDREMOS NUESTRA PAGINA Y EL LOGO*/'<a href = "nachetons/'+random+'"><img src="https://www.wndgroup.io/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/encryption-logo.jpg" alt="No cargo la imagen"/></a>',
            };


transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err) {
                console.log(email);

                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            });
```

Y aquí es donde comparo si el `token` es correcto que me cambie la contraseña, pero no me lo llega a hacer:

```
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err) {
                console.log(email);

                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            });



            exports.resetPasswordFinish = async(email, token, password) =>

                new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

                    user.find({ email: email })
                        .then(users => {
                            console.log(users);

                            let user = users[0];

                            const diff = new Date() - new Date(user.temp_password_time);
                            const seconds = Math.floor(diff / 1000);
                            console.log(`Seconds : ${seconds}`);

                            if (seconds < 120) {

                                return user;

                            } else {

                                reject({ status: 401, message: 'Time Out ! Try again' });
                            }
                        })

                        .then(user => {

                            if (bcrypt.compareSync(token, user.temp_password)) {

                                const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
                                const hash = bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);
                                user.hashed_password = password;
                                user.temp_password = undefined;
                                user.temp_password_time = undefined;
                                console.log(user);

                                return  user.update();

                            } else {

                                reject({ status: 401, message: 'Invalid Token !' });
                            }
                        })

                        .then(user => resolve({ status: 200, message: 'Password Changed Sucessfully !' }))

                        .catch(err => reject({ status: 500, message: 'Internal Server Error !' }));
                });
```

Comment: Sin código no podemos adivinar lo que sucede. Si aportas el código del middleware o del controlador que maneja la ruta, tal vez podríamos ayudar. Te invito a leer [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: Perdona ya añadi el transporter que tengo en el codigo añado lo de android tambien? es que estoy confundido no se si es fallo de android o de node creo que es de node

Comment: Analizaré tu lógica, pero de antemano te digo que: *toda función tipo `async` devuelve una promesa*, por lo tanto no es necesario declarar la función como `async` (*exports.resetPasswordFinish = async(email, token, password)*) si vas a devolver una promesa y no necesitas devolver una Promesa si tu función es `async`. Por otro lado, tu función no devuelve nada, deberías tener: *return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {*. Luego de analizar bien tu lógica creo que podré dar una respuesta. Saludos

Comment: El async si que lo necesito porque en la aplicación Android cuando le doy a olvidé mi contraseña me pide un correo se lo doy y en cuanto detecta que se envía el mensaje correctamente con el token me deja de cargar la barra y me lleva a el diálogo pidiendo el token el tema es que no me llega a cargar hasta esa parte me entra en el catch si en el catch pongo lo del diálogo visible pues no funciona y salen los errores